# What is the best helper method for volley to make get and post requests?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have got the following helper method to deal with volley.

```
public interface OnFinishListener { public void onFinish( JSONObject o ); }

public class VolleyHelper {

    public JSONObject get(String url, OnFinishListener ofl ) {

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                ofl.onFinish( jsonObject );
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //return jsonerror
            }
        });

        addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
}
```

Is there any other best practice helper method which is better than the above code?

Comment: You can improve your code using a singleton class. http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

Comment: if i user singleton, its like returning the response every time synchronously. It has to be asynchronous for better efficiency.

Comment: If your application makes constant use of the network, it's probably most efficient to set up a single instance of RequestQueue that will last the lifetime of your app. This is a google recomendation. Maybe if you want a more complete response should start to post a more complete answer.